# React: how to uncheck all checkbox on save

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am trying to create an audit form to make a list of patients and what alerts they have.  When I click the 'Save patient' button I want all the checkboxes to untick/reset themselves but I can't figure it out. I have set the state of alerts back to an empty array, but the checkboxes are still ticked.  Any help would be amazing as I am new to React :)

```
class AuditForm extends Component {
  state = {
hospitalNum: []
    alerts: [],
    list: [],
  };
  render() {
    const { alerts } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <Form>
          <Form.Row>
            <Form.Group>
              <Form.Label>Hospital Number</Form.Label>
              <Form.Control
                value={this.state.hospitalNum}
                type="string"
                onChange={this.handleHospNumChange}
              />
            </Form.Group>
             </Form.Row>
          <Form.Group>
            <Form.Check
              onChange={(e) => {
                this.updateAlertList(e, "MRSA");
              }}
              inline
              label="MRSA"
              type="checkbox"
              id="MRSA"
            />
            <Form.Check
              onChange={(e) => {
                this.updateAlertList(e, "cDiff");
              }}
              inline
              label="cDiff"
              type="checkbox"
              id="cDiff"
            />

          </Form.Group>
          <Button variant="primary" type="submit" onClick={this.saveData}>
            Save patient
          </Button>
        </Form>
      </div>
    );
  }

  saveData = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState((currentState) => {
      return {
        hospitalNum: [],
        alerts: [],
        list: [
          ...currentState.list,
          {
            hospitalNum: currentState.hospitalNum,
            alerts: currentState.alerts,
          },
        ],
      };
    });
  };


  handleHospNumChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({ hospitalNum: e.target.value });
  };


  updateAlertList = (e, alert) => {
    if (e.target.checked === false) {
      const filteredAlerts = this.state.alerts.filter(
        (prevAlert) => prevAlert !== alert
      );
      this.setState({ alerts: filteredAlerts });
    } else {
      this.setState((prevState) => {
        return {
          alerts: [...prevState.alerts, alert],
        };
      });
    }
  };
}

export default AuditForm;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the checked or unchecked values of the checkboxes in the state and after save you can setState the state as false for all checkboxes

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a checked property to each checkbox and check to see if that item exists in your state. Check out the react docs on [forms](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components) and read up on controlled components. The react docs are awesome and have helped me a lot.

Here's a possible solution:

```
<Form.Check
   onChange={(e) => {
     this.updateAlertList(e, "cDiff");
   }}
   inline
   label="cDiff"
   type="checkbox"
   id="cDiff"
   checked={this.state.alerts.includes("cDiff")}
/>
```

Then once you save you need to handle the form data and then set the alerts list back to an empty array.

Hope that helps!